# Paginación en php mostranto títulos diferentes

Tags: php, datatables, seo, paginación

Tengo varios ficheros que muestran datos de una base de datos. Es una paginación que muestra datos cada 10 registros. El caso es que todo funciona correctamente, pero el título de todas las páginas es el mismo: pagina1.php, pagina2.php, pagina3.php etc
No si si conoces algún ejemplo o tutorial, que pueda mostrar un título diferente en todas las páginas, ahora mismo el título es el siguiente

```
<title>listado de registros </title>
```

Este título aparece en todas las páginas, a efectos Seo es contenido duplicado. Lo que quiero que no hay que cambiar mucho sería:

```
<title>listado de registros 2</title>
<title>listado de registros 3</title>
<title>listado de registros 4</title>
```

Es ir agregando una numeración a cada título por cada página, de esta manera serían títulos distintos.

Os paso el código fuente que es más aclaratorio

```
<?php
/* conectamos con la base de datos*/
$conexion = mysqli_connect('localhost,'1458','csres17L');
mysqli_select_db($conexion, 'mensajes');

/*definimos los resultados por */
$resultados-pagina = 20;

/* seleccionamos todos los campos de la tabla*/
$sql='SELECT * FROM clientes';
$resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);
$numero-resultados= mysqli_num_rows($result);
/*determinamos el numero de páginas*/
$numero-paginas = ceil($numero-resultados $/resultados-pagina);

/* numero de visitas*/
if (!isset($_GET['page'])) {
  $pagina = 1;
} else {
  $pagina = $_GET['page'];
}
$primer-resultado = ($pagina1)*$resultados-pagina;
/* seleccionamos los datos de tabla por id*/
$sql='SELECT * FROM clientes ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT ' . $primer-resultado . ',' .  $resultados-pagina;
$primer-resultado . ',' .  $resultados-pagina;
$resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)) {
 
   echo $row['nombre'] . '<br>';
    echo $row['fecha']  . '<br>';
     echo $row['mensaje']  . '<br>';
     echo "<p></p>"; 
       echo  "<hr style='border-bottom: dotted 1px #F0F0F0' />";
     
  


  }

/* mostramos las páginas*/
for ($pagina=1;$pagina<=$numero-paginas;$pagina++) {
echo '<a href="feedback.php?pagina=' . $pagina . '" class="foro">' . $pagina . '</a> ';
}

?>
```

Comment: Es que de normal cuando haces un paginador no utilizas un archivo para cada 10 páginas... lo haces mediante código y tienes un único archivo que devuelve X o Y páginas en función de los parámetros que se le pasan. De todas maneras, cómo vamos a poder ayudarte si no podemos ver el código de cómo pintas ese `title`???

Comment: Aparte de lo que dice @Benito-B, es un error pensar incluir cada offset de datos en los resultados de búsqueda para fines SEO. Supongo que el paginador presenta datos dinámicos, por lo que no tendría ninguna utilidad para SEO indexar `N` grupo de resultados. A lo sumo indexarías la página de búsqueda en sí misma, que tendría una URL fija y los offset los cambiarías de forma dinámica sin siquiera cambiar la URL. Hoy día esto es perfectamente posible usando Ajax por ejemplo.

Comment: Revisa [este artículo](https://www.searchenginejournal.com/technical-seo/pagination/) de SEJ sobre la paginación y el SEO.

Answer (score 2):

No pusistema muestras de tu codigo pero supongo que si es php tus registros corresponden a un $_GET para cada pagina y si usas por ejemplo `$_GET['numero_de_pagina']`

tu codigo deberia ser este:

```
<title>Listado de registros <?=$_GET['numero_de_pagina'];?></title>
```

y si es con javascript que navegas por tus registros entonces te recomiendo usar esto:

```
document.title = "Listado de Registros n";
```

donde n es el numero de pagina.